# Finding a single record after a join

Tags: sql

I'm really new to SQL, but I am trying to join Runners with Races and find who won the 500m dash and bring back `first name`, `last name`, and `city`.

I can see `winner_id` is 3, which is equal to Alice Jones. Is it really this simple?

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, city 
FROM Runners 
INNER JOIN Races 
ON runners.id = races.winner_id
WHERE races.winner_id = 3
```

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWQdo.jpg)

Comment: Please do not show structure and data in pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find

> who won the 500m dash and bring back first name, last name, and city

You have to apply different condition to your query:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, city FROM Runners 
INNER JOIN Races ON runners.id = races.winner_id WHERE races.id = 2
```

So that you really filter on "500m dash" race, but not predicting who won that race, as in your initial query (`WHERE races.winner_id = 3`)